# How do I find an area as a function of only x?

Tags: calculus, functions, area

Some context: The pages of a children's book are to contain 72 square inches of printed matter and illustrations, with margins of 1 inch along the sides and 2 inches along the top and bottom of each page. Find the dimensions of the page that will require the minimum amount of paper.
Upon working on the first few steps, I know that x*y=72. Since the margins are given, the page length is x+4 and the page width is x+2.
My question is how do I find the area equation? The problem shows the solution of A(x)=80+2x+(288/x) and I'm wondering how to get this solution; again, I'm wondering how to find this equation and not solve the rest of the problem yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the area $(x+4)(y+2)$ and substitute $y=72/x$ to get $80+2x+288/x$.